# Multiple Backgrounds with Smooth scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been playing with my site learning css/html/javascript but there is just one thing that I cannot get, how to do Multiple Backgrounds to get this Cool effect like you can find right here ;

https://allods.my.com/en/news

I this smooth scrolling and those multiple backgrounds are just awesome! What should I know to start creating such things? Is it pure css or is it more?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I mean the main menu is just still and it seems like the other parts of site are moving how can i do that?

Comment: If you want to find tutorials or guides on how to code something like this, search for "parallax".

Comment: Oh thank you my friend!

Answer (score 0):

For parallax scrolling, I suggest you check out this library: http://scrollmagic.io/

It's complicated at first, but very powerful and should be able to replicate the effects you are looking for.